# I can not connect to postgres amazon rds in rails

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

below is my `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <my_aws_end_url>
  database: <my_db_name>
  pool: 5432
  username: <my_username>
  password: <my_password>
```

The error I am getting is as followed:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
```

I have verified the end url in aws and have my inbound set to all traffic. I have also tried to connect using pgadmin and got the same error.

Comment: If you can't connect with pgadmin then this has nothing to do with Rails. It's purely related to your AWS or local system configuration. Voted to close; try serverfault.com

Comment: A timeout is usually related to a Security Group. The security group on Amazon RDS should include an Inbound rule that permits port 5432 from where ever the connection is coming from.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I currently have the inbound rule to accept all

Comment: From where are you making the connection -- EC2 instance, Lambda function, etc?